# Google Play - Difference between Low Maturity and Medium Maturity

Tags: android, google-play, rating

What changes if you you choose a *Low Maturity* over *Medium Maturity* [rating for a Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en) Android app? Will the app only be displayed to users with a certain age?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about terms, conditions, and operation of a catalog for a distribution channel, not programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Will the app only be displayed to users with a certain age?

Not Age. Playstore app has filters; and based on those filters, apps will be visible to the users.
So if your app has a rating of **Medium Maturity** and I have set my Playstore app's filter settings to **Low Maturity**, your app won't be visible to me.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en-IN

**Everyone**
Applications in this category should not collect user's location data or contain objectionable material. Applications should not share user content or include social features.

**Low Maturity**
Applications in this category may include instances of mild cartoon or fantasy violence or other potentially offensive content. Applications may collect user location data for the purpose of providing location specific information or otherwise improving the user experience, but should not share the data with other users. Applications may include some social features but should not focus on allowing users to find and communicate with each other.

**Medium Maturity**
Applications in this category may include sexual references; intense fantasy or realistic violence; profanity or crude humor; references to drug, alcohol and tobacco use; social features and simulated gambling. Applications may collect user location data for the purpose of sharing or publishing with the user's consent.

**High Maturity**
Applications in this category may focus on or include frequent instances of sexual and suggestive content; graphic violence; social features; simulated gambling; and strong alcohol, tobacco and drug references. Applications may collect user location data for the purpose of sharing or publishing with the user's consent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the default filter set to "Everyone"?

Comment: Yes. Since I haven't  touched my play store settings and it is set on "Show all apps" which was the 5th filter apart from everyone, low, medium and high maturity. Though I'm still on gingerbread.

Comment: why i am unable to check for everyone>

Comment: What do you mean by 'social features'? I have a 'Like' button, and from within my application user can share Facebook pages & videos on his timeline or via other means, so shall I rate it to 'Low Maturity'?

Comment: And how to set such filter? I want to change "Everyone" to "Low Maturity", here more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134528/rating-for-ads-google-console-and-12-ad-failed-to-load-3-with-g