# Rating for ads, Google Console and 12+, "Ad failed to load : 3" with "G"

Tags: android, admob

I received from Google Play Developer Support next message for my new app update

> The ads shown within your app must be appropriate for the intended
>   audience of your app, even if the content by itself is otherwise
>   compliant with our policies. For example, ads that show mature content
>   or services cannot be served in apps that have a content rating for
>   younger audiences.

(as I understand they want to say if your app has age rating 3+ then your ads should have the same rating)

I found a solution to solve it like this

`max_ad_content_rating` to `"G"` which is for 3+ rating (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting)

```
private void requestAd() {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras).build();
    mAdView.setAdListener(mBannerAdListener);
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

But I'm not sure how good it is for out profit, I mean if there are ads only suitable for 3+ (for children), no one will click on such ads

I found out that YouTube app (com.google.android.youtube package) has **12+** rating and it's being displayed like this on its Google Play page:

[image]

How did they set this **Parental Guidance**?

Most apps have **3+** rating and to get 12+ or more you have to set that your app's content has some sexuality, violent, etc during **questionnaire** for content rating at Google Console

In this **questionnaire** I didn't find anything that would calculate my rating as **Parental Guidance** 12+

I tried to set a little bit sexuality for my app :) during questionnaire but it calculated rating as 12+ not for all countries, for Russia it set 16+

Does Google just set anything they want for their apps and doesn't allow other developers to set something like this as well?

p.s. table of age ratings

[image]

**UPDATE (Ad failed to load)**

I uploaded new update for my app which includes `"max_ad_content_rating", "G"` and ads stopped loading (displaying)...

I tried to check logs of my phone and I found out there `Ad failed to load : 3` messages when I start my app

Awesome...

**UPDATE 2**

Ads are only displayed if I set `extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "MA");` which is the highest rating (16+,18+) and of course it works ok if I don't set such extra filter at all

other ones (`"G"`, `"PG"`, `"T")` fails with `Ad failed to load : 3` error

Comment: I run to this issues as well.it is so complicated.why google cant handle this mess automatically?

Comment: Do u realoved it somehow?

Comment: @yarin choice is yours: setting `max_ad_content_rating`, blocking sensitive categories (using Admob site), making your app's rating higher (Google Console) even if your app doesn't contain any sensitive content, ignoring Google's messages (though it's not recommended)

Comment: @user924 according to your experience, blocking sensitive categories from Admob dashboard without setting extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G"); for 3+ content rating will work?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 I didn't test this method, but some other users mentioned about this in similar issues here

Comment: @user924 thanks, I'll update this if I have any new info

Comment: After all did you artificially increased your content rating to 12+ on Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

I got app rejection email

> Ad content​
>   The ad content in your app is not consistent with the app's content rating. To resolve this issue, please remove ad content not consistent with your app’s rating and/or retake the content rating questionnaire and include your ad content. If you monetize your app, please ensure you’ve excluded ads from sensitive categories. For more details, you can refer to the “Ads” section (#3) of the Families Policy Requirements.

So that I realized that I have 3+ rating on Google Play but it doesn't match with my Google AdMod settings.

I blocked all **sensitive categories** as it was suggested in the letter:

[image]

And I left **AD CONTENT RATING** as **MA**:

[image]

Then I resubmitted the app and after ~24 hours it was published successfully.